# How to send a valid regex in botium

Tags: botium-box

I'm working on a nodejs framework with botium tests (not botium box)

The botium card is as following:

```
Rejected referrals

#me
rejected referrals

#bot
"You have * Rejected referrals."  
CARDS referral
```

My error is Rejected referrals/Line 6: Expected bot response (on Line 3: #me - rejected referrals) 
ASSERTION FAILED in TextMatchAsserter - Expected: "You have * Rejected referrals."  - Actual: "You have 152 Rejected referrals."

Wildcard was just added to botium: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-core/issues/387 Is this only for botium box and not botium?

Comment: try without the "

Answer (score 0):

Omit the quotation marks.

```
Rejected referrals

#me
rejected referrals

#bot
You have * Rejected referrals.
CARDS referral
```